# Reputation points lost for no reason

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I lost 2 reputation points for no reason.

In the reputation log I see only an entry:

```
-2 removed The Android web driver client does not load fully
```

But I have never created such a post.

Why is so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That post is found [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2835/the-android-web-driver-client-does-not-load-fully), but is deleted by owner.

You made edits to the post which were approved in the review queue, which gave you +2 reputation.

When the post was deleted, you lost those 2 reputation points.